# React Nodejs prblem with API call

Tags: javascript, express

I am new to NodeJs, I created several APIs for my application with different methods and they all work fine, the issue is that I created a new API in the same file where I have the others but when calling it from my FE it is called twice, one is prefligth with options method and another is pending but without method... Attached screenshots..[API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy2UL.png)

This is my API code:

```
router.put("/carrousel-item/update/:id", fileUpload, (req, res) => {
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
try {
  const image = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, "../images/" + req.file.filename)
  );
  const title_en = req.body.title_en;
  const title_es = req.body.title_es;
  const sub_title_color_1_en = req.body.sub_title_color_1_en;
  const sub_title_color_1_es = req.body.sub_title_color_1_es;
  const sub_title_color_2_en = req.body.sub_title_color_2_en;
  const sub_title_color_2_es = req.body.sub_title_color_2_es;
  try {
    conn.query(
      `UPDATE home_team_section SET ? WHERE id = ?`,
      [
        {
          title_en: title_en,
          title_es: title_es,
          sub_title_color_1_en: sub_title_color_1_en,
          sub_title_color_1_es: sub_title_color_1_es,
          sub_title_color_2_en: sub_title_color_2_en,
          sub_title_color_2_es: sub_title_color_2_es,
          image: image,
        },
      ],
      (err, rows) => {
        res.send(rows);
      }
    );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
  });
});
```

This problem is not letting me advance with the project since it does not let me execute any new API

Note: I have added the cors()

I hope you can help me

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with your CORS config at all. Empty `catch` blocks, never checking `err` and not sending a response when errors occur is probably your issue. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score -1):

```
const ModelLabel = require("../models/modelLabel")
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

class ControllerLable{
    static label(request,response){
        ModelLabel.renderLabel((err,data)=>{
            if (err) {
                response.send(err)
            }else{
                // console.log(data);
                response.render('labelView',{ newResult:data })
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   static addSongGet(cb){
        let query=`
        SELECT l."name",l.id FROM "Labels" l;`
        pool.query(query,(err, res)=>{
            if (err) {
                cb(err)
            }else{
                let newResult=res.rows
                cb(null,newResult)
            }
        })}

    static addSongPost(request,cb){
        
        const title1=request.body.title
        const bandName1=request.body.bandName
        const duration1=request.body.duration
        const genre1=request.body.genre
        const lyric1=request.body.lyric
        const imageUrl1=request.body.imageUrl
        const label1=request.body.label
        const createdAt1=request.body.createdAt

        let error=[]
        if (!title1) {
            error.push("Title is required")
        }
        if (title1.length>=100) {
            error.push("Title maximum character is 100")
        }
        if (!bandName1) {
            error.push("BandName is required")
        }
        if (!duration1) {
            error.push("Duration is required")
        }
        if (duration1<60) {
            error.push("Minimum Duration is 60 second")
        }
        if (!genre1) {
            error.push("Genre is required")
        }
        if (!lyric1) {
            error.push("Lyric is required")
        }
        if (lyric1) {
            let countSpace=0
            for (let i = 0; i < lyric1.length; i++) {
                if (lyric1[i]===" ") {
                    countSpace++
                }
            }
            // console.log(countSpace);
            if (countSpace<10) {
                error.push("Minimum word in lyric is 10")
            }
        }
        if (!imageUrl1) {
            error.push("Image Url is required")
        }
        if (imageUrl1<=50) {
            error.push("ImageUrl name maximum character is 50")
        }
        if (!label1) {
            error.push("Label Company is required")
        }
        if (!createdAt1) {
            error.push("Date is required")
        }
        if (createdAt1) {
            let currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
            if (createdAt1>currentDate) {
                error.push("Maximum created date is today")
            }
        }
        // console.log(error);
        
        if (error.length!==0) {
            // console.log(error);

            cb(error)
        }else{
            let vote;
            const {title,bandName,duration,genre,lyric,imageUrl,label,createdAt}=request.body
            const values=[title,bandName,duration,genre,createdAt,lyric,imageUrl,vote=0,label]
            let query=`
            INSERT INTO "Songs" ("title","bandName","duration","genre","createdDate",lyric,"imageUrl","totalVote","LabelId") 
            VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9);`
            pool.query(query,values,(err,res)=>{
                if (err) {
                    cb(err)
                    console.log('QUERY EROR');
                }else{
                    console.log("Data berhasil ditambahkan");
                    cb(null,1)
                }
            })
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: this model for addget post